# Algorithm for placing n points equidistantly

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I don't know whether this is the appropriate place (in negative case, please redirect the question, I suppose in Mathematics). Basicly I have a rectangle and I have to place n ports (on the left side, equidistantly from the center and from the nearest "last point" of the side) and m ports (on the right side, equidistantly from the center and from the nearest "last point" of the side). The ports are also small rectangles, but is not important.

For example, let's suppose that my rectangle is 50px X 50px and I have 1 input port and 2 output ports. In this case I have to place the input port in (x:0,y: 25) and the output ports in positions (x:50, y:10) and (x:50, y:40). Of course the problem is about y-coordinate.

I don't know the number of input and output ports a priori, so I have to write a method to calculate y-coordinates automatically. Is there any built in algorithm for this?

Comment: A built-in algorithm in JavaScript for placing points equidistantly on a rectangle? No.

Comment: @EvanKnowles  Not exactly rectangle, let's say "in a line", since the problem is about one coordinate (y)

Comment: I don't get it, so how would this work with 3 'ports'

Comment: Why (y:10) (y:40) and not for example (y:17) (y:33)?

Comment: I don't get the 10 and 40: They're 10px from the side, and 30px from each other.

Comment: Would (50,0),(50,50) also be solutions in your example?

Comment: Would you mind promoting your post from a puzzle to a valid question ?

Comment: I'm not certain you can place more than two points on a line equidistantly in any case.

Comment: @Kos the ports have to be equidistant from the center of the side. The side is 50, the center is in 25, so 10 is far 15 from 25, and 40 is far 15 from 25

Comment: @LevKuznetsov with 3 ports (odd case) I could place one in the center of the side (25), so I will have 2 sub sides, with length 25 and 25. I can place the second port in (50, 12.5) and the third in (50, 37.5). There is a logic I guess

Comment: By that logic 2 points should be 16.666 and 33.333. You divide 50 by number of points + 1 and that's your length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could divide the side of the the rectangle into n+1 or m+1 segments of equal length: if the side has a length of H, the length of a segment would be h=H/(n+1), so your ports would be at location (y) h,2*h,3*h...